# Encog Framework not giving acceptable error rate

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, encog

I have a very small dataset, only 200 rows.  I have only 3 columns; the first two are numeric (negative and positive) and the last is letter.

I am attempting to classify the last column based on the first two numeric columns.

My comma separated data looks similar to this (before normalization):

```
Home Team Line,Away Team Line,Winner
-6,0,H
-8,0,H
0,-21,A
etc...
```

Example data after normalization:

```
HomeTeamLine,AwayTeamLine,Winner-p0,Winner-p1
-0.40493939,1,-1,0
-0.22929292,1,-1,0
-1,-0.9233003,0,-1
```

I have tried every method I could think of including Propagation and Simulated Neural Annealing, but the Encog Framework still can't find a pattern.

My code looks similar to this (writing from memory):

```
// build network
BasicNetwork network = new BasicNetwork();

network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, 2));
network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, 14));
network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, 2));
network.Structure.FinalizeStructure();

network.Reset();

// train network
var trainingSet = // load training CSV
ITrain train = new ResilientPropagation(network, trainingSet);

do
{
  train.Iteration();
  Console.WriteLine("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:" + train.Error);
  epoch++;
} while (train.Error > 0.001);
```

My error rate never goes below 74%.

**I assume the problem is that I am not using enough data rows, or that I am not using enough features (columns), or that there simply is no pattern in the data.**

What would be the recommended approach to achieving an acceptable error rate?

Comment: How are you creating the ideal value for your trainingSet? Just a sugestion, since you have 2 outputs neurons, you could create and `ideal` value using the `double[][]` with a binary value, for sample: for `H`: `new double[] { 1 , 0 }` and for `A`: `new double[] { 0 , 1 }`.

Comment: Thanks.  The normalized data does use two columns: `H = -1,0` and `A = 0,-1` or vise versa.  I am not sure if that is what you mean?  I specified this column as `OneOf` action method.

Comment: yes, you understand what I was trying to say. Since you use the `ActivationTANH` as activation function, you should normalize the output to the right interval compatible with `ActivationTANH`, `-1` and `1`.

Comment: I also would add the stop condition for `epoch` for sample: `while (epoch < 10000 && train.Error > 0.001);`.

Comment: I have a `Stop` strategy included, but it just stops somewhere between 74% and 98%.  I updated my question with an example of what my normalized data looks like.

Comment: I think I am going to try some of these next, I'll let you know how it goes: hybrid strategy, reset strategy, required improvement strategy, smart learning rate strategy, and smart momentum strategy.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just keep in mind you have to normalize according your activation function, for TangH the interval is -1 and 1, for Sigmoid is 0 and 1.

Comment: @FelipeOriani Still not much improvement.  The hybrid strategy was slightly more effective than previous strategies.  I am not sure I understand your comment, "Just keep in mind you have to normalize according your activation function, for TangH the interval is -1 and 1, for Sigmoid is 0 and 1."  Am I not doing this?  My normalized data ranges from -1 to 1 and my activation methods are `ActivationTANH`.

Answer (score 1):

I have another clarification. You have two outputs from Neural network, but in task description you say "I am attempting to classify the last column based on the first two numeric columns" which sounds for me that you have two inputs and one output. Why do you have another output? Another proposal is to add one more hidden layer. I don't recommend to add more then two hidden layers, because in that case error function

> As errors propagate from layer to layer, they shrink exponentially with the number of layers. As mentioned http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning

Comment: The two outputs `Winner-p0,Winner-p1` are because encog normalizes the data.

Comment: From NN prospective it looks like you want to give to NN two inputs and get two outputs.